# HP Proliant Gen 8 Micro Server with ESXI installe connected to BT HomeHub

Tags: wireless-router, esxi, hp-proliant, bt-infinity, esxi5.5

I have HP Proliant Microserver on its way, I intend on installing ESXI on it and have it physically connected to my home hub router.

Now will I be able to connect to it wirelessly, from my Pc with the client installed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.

Unless you have a very specific configuration, all the machines connected to your home router, either wired of wireless, will get an IP in the same network (likely 192.168.X.X) and can communicate with each other.

Comment: Excellent, questioning myself for no reason. Good to know that wireless connection will be just the same for server connected to router.